# How do you test namespace post :post routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have these route

```
# routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :departments
end
```

And following code in controller test. It fails because **post :create** is not heading to **admin_departments_path**. What is the correct way to write this?

```
# test/functional/admin/departments_controller_test.rb 
# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches (FAIL)
post :create, :department => @new_department.attributes
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` say about your generated routes?

Comment: rake routes gives me admin_departments (GET & POST). This I already know, I'm just not sure how to test this post :create, :department (where do I put the "admin" part)

Comment: Show us what (FAIL) is, that'd be helpful.

Comment: "ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches" is the error returned when running rake test:units. Obviously, since "post :create, :department" department is wrong. This is what I'm not sure how, since "post :create, :department" definitely points to departments_url instead of admin_departments_url

Comment: Does the test class include the namespace? Eg. `class Admin::DepartmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase`

Comment: Thanks Zetetic, that solved it, didn't notice that.

Comment: @zetetic: You may want to create an answer with the info from your comment, so Ed_ might accept it. This question would then not be listed amongst unanswered ones, and will not raise my hopes on finding an easy prey ;)

Answer (score -3):

Controller tests are needlessly painful and too closely coupled to implementation. Don't use them.

The correct way to do this is to write a Cucumber scenario that posts something to the form, then checks that you ended up on the page you wanted to.